# How to deploy a Go web application to a server?

Tags: go, deployment, server, hosting

This is a very noob question, so please understand and take that into account.
I have a basic go web app and a server running Ubuntu 22.04 with a domain which I bought from hosting provider. They installed an also ISPManager control panel there. But the control panel does not provide a way  (from what I've seen) to host a Go application there, only PHP anf python for the most part.
I don't have any knowledge of web servers like Apache or Nginx, but I know some Linux CLI, and I have written the web app myself. I can also SSH into the server.

I tried running an app by just using go run, but in that case (predictably) I had to enter an IP address of a server along with a port name.

How can I host my app there?

Comment: Please stop using go run. `go run` is a nice shortcut e.g. during development. Just get used to compile your code with go build.

Comment: @Volker well, I can understand this, but even if I use that method I still cannot access that using domain name

Comment: Reach out to me (taleodor) at Discord devopscommunity.org - assuming it's a small project - we may be able to help you at no cost using our platform - Reliza Hub - for managing deployments.

Comment: @taleodor thank you for help. The issue here is that there is a bit more context, the site is for a local place where I work, and they are building a residential complex, and they need a particular domain for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by setting up the domain name into the ip address of the server, the hosting provider gives a way to do that.

Comment: Hi where did you run the golang exe file from? I have a golang server that I built and I want to run it in the domain server that I purchased.

Comment: @AllieMoosa do you use Windows as a server os? I used Ubuntu 22.04 and compiled go code for it.

Comment: I am using wsl(ubuntu) and I want to run the golang exe on domain.
Note: I already added the file in my domain.

Comment: @AllieMoosa You cannot run windows compiled exe file on WSL or Linux, so you'd have to install go on WSL and compile the program there as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access it means that you also have permission to transfer files from remote with sftp or scp etc. So in basics you just need to compile your code and then transfer it to the server with protocols I mentioned or you may use applications like filezilla. Then you need to install a load balancer you can use nginx and there is a simple guide for installing and configuring you may follow [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04). The other thing you need to do is configuring public dns with A record maybe. As a summary it is not a really simple thing to achieve, I recommend you to find a support from someone (maybe freelancer.). I hope this answer finds you well...

Regards,

Comment: Gosh... I did not expect such answers, but still thank you for being so honest with me. At least you made it clear that it's not simple.
I hope I will be able to do that in the end...

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask in that platform if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use one of the myriads of clouds that automatically manages your app, is just so much easier to run, scale, monitor, view logs ... etc:

I strongly suggest you try the cloud run, as if free unless you are really putting it to heavy work. But if you just need a service that is REST-API or a  web-site just go with the first link.

[GCP Cloud Run (my favorite) has also free tier](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-go-service)

[Amazon ECS](https://medium.com/tysonworks/deploy-go-applications-to-ecs-using-aws-cdk-1a97d85bb4cb)

and if you do a search there are many more with free tier

Comment: AFAIR you cannot get a particular domain name with it, which I need.

Comment: you can, all you need is to configure it https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains .